# Import error while uploading a CSV file in Oracle NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, netsuite-rest-api

I want upload the bank statement using import option Oracle NetSuite, but I am receiving an error:

> The file could not be imported, because there is an incorrect number
> of CSV columns in the header: 1. For specifications, check with your
> file provider.

However, I have removed all of the special characters from the header and uploaded and I am still getting the same error.

I have attached the screenshot for your reference.

I have tried from Mac and Windows, both are not working.